# direnv runs in emulated x86_64 environment

Tags: bash, macos, shell, direnv

direnv is running in an emulated environment with Rosetta, despite my shell running in a normal environment. I am on mac osx and recently ran the migration tool from an x86_64 to M2 macbook pro.

- My shell is running in a normal environment, confirmed with arm64 output from `uname -m`
- direnv runs in an emulated environment, confirmed with x86_64 output from `direnv exec . uname -m`
- Uninstalling and reinstalling direnv does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed direnv with Homebrew. Homebrew itself was Rosetta enabled, running `brew config` will output `Rosetta: true`. I fixed the problem by doing the following:

1. Uninstall homebrew with the instructions [here](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew).
2. Reinstall homebrew with the instructions [here](https://github.com/homebrew/install#install-homebrew-on-macos-or-linux)
3. Reinstall direnv with homebrew: `brew install direnv`

Hope this helps others running into the same problem.